# Extrude/Scale evenly in a mirrored circle

Tags: mesh

I use the mirror modifier to mirror a circle shape. Now I want to add a lip on the end, but with even width all the way around. But I can't get this to work because the origin seems to be off center. Is there a way to do that?

[image]

Comment: How does your initial situation look like? Could you add a picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pivot in the circle's center

The origin of the trasformation in your current setup is probably set to "median point", so the scaling is using the baricenter of the geometry as pivot point.

This is usually not a problem while scaling a full circle, as the baricenter of the whole points is in the exact location of the center of the circle.

If you are controlling just half of the point, you should switch to another type of pivot point, that allows you to set the center of the circle as pivot for the transformation.

I'll suggest to use the 3D cursor as shown in the image sequence below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Cario, but how to move the 3 cursor into the correct position?

Comment: Whit Shiftt+S you can move the cursor. You'll have to provide a proper selection which depends on your geometry and what are you willing to do. Do you have an example?

Comment: @Cario Relized that selecting the two outermost vertices on the arch and move cursor to selected. However, this would only work for a semi-cirlce. How to move the cursor to the origin if the arch is not exactly pi?

Comment: You can select the vertices and move the 3D cursor to the origin of the selection, then set the x coordinate of the 3D cursor to 0, where the simmetry axis is.